# SQL: Alternative to COALESCE() function that groups all values into one column

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I have a table like this

[image]

Using the COALESCE() function...

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1, column2, column3) combinedColumn from t;
```

I get this...

[image]

However, I want this....

[image]

I found a work around using UNION ALL but this isn't very elegant. Is there a function that works like COALESCE() except includes all values? Thanks

Comment: How do you determine the order?

Comment: Order is not important in this case. I just want to combine all values into one column

Comment: There is a very good example in the next link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows ; try to adapt to work on your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a coalesce here as there might be more than one value to return

UNION is the best solution (not UNION ALL because blanks)

```
select column1 from mytable
UNION
select column2 from mytable
UNION
select column3 from mytable
```

That said, if you want to maintain duplicates (if any), it's UNION ALL, or joining all the columns into a single string then splitting them out again (avoiding the UNION ALL at any cost)